# How to fetch printers and select a specific printer in Expo React Native for Android?

Tags: javascript, react-native, printing, expo

I'm working on a React Native project using Expo, and I need to implement printer selection functionality for Android. In iOS, I'm able to use Print.selectPrinterAsync() to fetch the list of available printers and select a specific printer. However, it seems that this method is only available for iOS and not for Android in Expo.

I have tried using Print.selectPrinterAsync() on Android, but it throws an error indicating that the method is not available.

Is there any alternative or workaround to fetch the list of printers and select a specific printer in Expo React Native for Android? I want to achieve similar functionality as Print.selectPrinterAsync() but for Android.

Here is the code snippet I have tried:

```
import * as Print from 'expo-print';

const getPrinters = async () => {
  try {
    const printerList = await Print.selectPrinterAsync();
    setAvailablePrinters(printerList);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error fetching printers:', error);
  }
};
```

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue.